# Does OrderID Depends on QuoteID with time and in the sequence of IncrementIDs?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database

I was working on Magento Payment Gateway. I got a weird doubt about Order generation and it happened to me.

1) We just added some products to the Cart long back (2 months back) for one test user.

2) Later on we got many orders in this period of 2 months.

3) Now we just logged in with that test user and luckily we have items in the cart and we placed order.

Here it is a new Order anyways and it should match with the last Increment ID right ?

But we received Order ID which matches 2 months back orderIDs.

How it happened ? I studied about Order Processing But No where I found Solution for this.

Please let me know the things how it happened..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Has i know the order increment id is independent of cart (quote) ids.
The cart does not have any information about the order increment id. The order increment id will be generated when you finish your order and the number will follow the actual incrementation, does not matter if you added the products to the cart today or a month ago.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I still didn't  clear insight on this. As you said *"The order increment id will be generated when you finish your order and the number will follow the actual incrementation"* . In this Case the `sales_flat_order` has `entity_id` it should treat orders as *FIRST COME FIRST SERVE*. It didn't happened to me Why it was generating **OrderID**s with Gaps.